# echo command displays to the screen even though loop directs to output file

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to get the md5 of every individual line item and dump each md5 into a line on the next file (.md5). The below script echos everything to the screen. How do I redirect the echo output to the .md5 file.

```
more email/test | 
while 
read line; 
md5=`md5sum $line | awk '{ print $1 }'`
do echo -n $md5; 
done < .md5
```

Comment: `<` redirects input. `>` redirects output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `bash`

Try:

```
while IFS= read -r line;
do
    md5sum $line | awk '{ print $1 }'
done <email/test >.md5
```

#### Using `awk`

The bash loop is unnecessary:

```
awk '{ "md5sum " $0 | getline; print $1}' email/test >.md5
```